# Python: Attempting to find a word in a string from HTTPRequest

Tags: python, html, string, find, httprequest

I'm trying to find a way to search the source code of a web page to see if it contains a key word. However, no matter what I search for on this page, the only result I get is -1, which I think is telling me I'm doing something wrong. Otherwise, I think it should tell me the position of when the word starts. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here's the code.

```
import urllib.request
page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
print(page.read())

str_page = str(page)

substring = "content"

print(str_page.find("lang"))
```

Comment: `page` is the url request object -- it is not the page _content_.  You can fetch the page content with `page.read()`, which you did, but you didn't save it to a variable.

Comment: @JohnGordon  Good enough for an answer, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2

webUrl  = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.youtube.com/user/guru99com')
print ("result code: " + str(webUrl.getcode()))
data = webUrl.read()
Source_text = (data)
Keyword = 'your keyword'
if Keyword in Source_text: 
     #put whatever you want here
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if the below mentioned code helps

```
import urllib.request

url = "http://www.google.com"

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

html = response.read().decode('utf-8','ignore')  # decode the html page here 
if 'lang' in html:
    print (html.find("lang"))  # gives the position of lang
```

Kindly decode() the html page may be that will be help out .